# Vichuploader File is not saved with post request

Tags: php, file, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

my project is actually to create a website that permit me to post gif, jpg etc..

I'm using VichuploaderBundler to upload a file and save it to a specific repository in my app

> ```
> #vich uploader Configuration
> vich_uploader:
>      db_driver: orm
>      mappings:
>         product_image:
>             uri_prefix:         /images/posts
>             upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/posts'
>             namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
>             inject_on_load:     false
>             delete_on_update:   true
>             delete_on_remove:   true
> ```

I'm creating an API to create and render ressources.

I'm trying to create a Post with a post request with postman.
In this Post i want to save an image throw vichuploader.(this had worked with a classical form).

Here is my problem :

My post is created thx to my postman request. But the file that i upload is not saved in the

```
                 /**
                 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
                 * @Rest\Post("/posts")
                 */
                public function postPostsAction(Request $request)
                {
                    $post = new Post();
                    $post->setTitle($request->get('title'))
                        ->setDescription($request->get('description'))
                        ->setImageName($request->get('image_name'))
                        ->setImageFile($request->get('imageFile'))

                        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
                        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
                        ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());


                    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
                    $em->persist($post);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $post;
                }
```

[image: Here is my postman]

Thx for helping and feedback about my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find how to fixed this, it was very simply in fact !

```
public function postPostsAction(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->setTitle($request->get('title'))
        ->setDescription($request->get('description'))
        ->setImageName($request->get('image_name'))
        ->setImageFile($request->files->get('imageFile'))
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        ->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());


    // On fait appel à doctrine pour seter un id lors de la création en base
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();

    return $post;
}
```

Thanks to the ->files statement my pictures are saved in the right directory